# C# - executing 200 http get requests and output the results

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, parallel-processing, console-application

I have an console app where the user inputs an menu option (1-5), I execute some feature and output the result.

One of the features is to execute 200 http get requests to some url, get all the results back, do some work on them and output to the user.

**This my current code:**

```
        Parallel.For(0, 200, i =>
        {
            String[] words = webApi.getSplittedClassName();
            for (int j = 0; j < words.Length; j++)
            {
                wordsList.Add(words[j]);
            }

        });
```

and **getSplittedClassName**:

```
    public string[] getSplittedClassName()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        try
        {
            response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return parser.breakdownClassName(response);
    }
```

Now, since the user inputs a option number, the program executess the required feature and then I put the output, I thought there is not point of doing the http work in async, so its all synchronously.

The issue is that it is taking A LOT of time to do the requests, about 30-40 secconds.. does that make sense?

There are 3 features basically: do 1 request, do 3 requests and 200 requests.

What is the best option of doing the 200 requests and wait for all the results? should it be synchronously like when I only send out one request?

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do 200 GET requests? Could you not combine the requests in to one and do the processing on the server and just return what you want to output to the user?

Comment: no I cant, its part of the exercise.. i need to do the 200 requests fast and in best practice, work on the results and output..

Comment: Why are you choosing not to do this asynchronously? Is there a reason that it should be synchronous?

Comment: because for 1 request and for 3 requests I didn't think its needed, but I guess now it would be much faster. I am just looking for a simple example of how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parallel.For()` tends to assume that your operations are mostly CPU-bound, so it'll use a degree of parallelism that's tuned to how many CPU cores your machine has. But HTTP Requests tend to be IO-bound, so most of your time is spent just waiting for the target machine to send information back to you.

That means that this is a good opportunity to use Asynchronous processing. Try something like this:

```
public async Task<string[]> getSplittedClassName()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    return parser.breakdownClassName(response);
}
```

and this:

```
    var classNameTasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 200)
        .Select(i => webApi.getSplittedClassName())
        .ToArray();
    wordList.AddRange(
        Task.WhenAll(classNameTasks).Result
            .SelectMany(g => g));
```

Explanation:

1. Make `getSplittedClassName()` *async* so that rather than getting the stuff it needs synchronously and then returning the result, it immediately returns a `Task<>` that will be completed when the result is available.
2. I removed the code that eats all exceptions, because that's generally a bad practice. You should think about what you'd really want to do if there was an exception here: should you retry the request? Just let the exception be thrown? It's typically a bad idea to just ignore problems like this.
3. `Task.WhenAll()` will return a `Task<>` that will return all of the results of the given tasks. You can synchronously wait for all those tasks to complete, then add them all to `wordList` as a batch. This is thread-safe because all the items are added to `wordList` on a single thread, whereas your original code had multiple threads potentially trying to add values to `wordList` at the same time.

Also, I'm assuming this is just a homework assignment, but if this were a real-world scenario, the fact that you're doing 200 GET requests to the same URL at the same time would be a big red flag.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it is an homework assignment, but  it still takes about 40-50 seconds to complete all the requests.. is that normal? plus, the options of 1 request and 3 requests should be done synchronously  right?

Comment: @OfekAgmon: It's hard to say whether that's normal, because I have no idea how the target server is set up. How long does it usually take for a request to return? And how much performance degradation can the target server see when it's handling concurrent requests? And I don't see any reason to treat 1 or 3 requests any differently: HTTP requests are an inherently asynchronous operation, so there's no compelling reason from a performance perspective to force your code to behave synchronously.

Comment: okay, thanks a lot. one more small thing - the method where I put the two lines of code you posted (the Enumerable.Range) has the signature of "public async Task execFeature", and there is a warning saying that I am not using the "await" and hence the method will run synchronously. is that even relevant? because I have all of the methods all the way up the chain of calls being async and returning Task of some sort, and the first call in program.cs is featureService.startService().Wait(). should it be like that? thanks a million

Comment: @OfekAgmon: If that method is already `async`, then you should use `(await Task.WhenAll(classNameTasks))` instead of `Task.WhenAll(classNameTasks).Result`.